# Диспетчер задач на с++

Tags: c++

пишу курсовую работу(диспетчер задач) не могу вывести список действующих процессов в листбокс. В документации по visual studio 2019 я не могу найти как это реализовать, а в коде с других форумов путаюсь. Можете поделиться кусочком кода, а ещё лутше если объясните как реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Только недавно делал такое, правда в контексте поиска процесса с заданным именем файла. Имеется некоторая проблема - код написан на C++17.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

using PIDVector=vector<DWORD>;
using HMODULEVector=vector<HMODULE>;
template<typename T> bool autoFill(T& vec,std::function<WINBOOL(typename T::value_type*, DWORD, DWORD*)> filler)
{
    //вычисляем размер одного элемента массива
    constexpr auto itmSize=sizeof(typename T::value_type);
    while(true)
    {
        DWORD cnt;
        const auto status=filler(vec.data(), vec.size()*itmSize, &cnt);
        if(!status)
        {
            //в случае ошибки, выходим
            return false;
        }

        //нам приходит размер данных в байтах, а нужно - в штуках
        const auto nItems=cnt/itmSize; 

        if(nItems>=vec.size())
        {
            //если буфер мал - увеличить
            vec.resize( nItems + 1024);
        }
        else
        {
            vec.resize( nItems );
            return true;
        }
    }
}

void findProcess()
{
    const auto fName=procName.toUpper();   

    PIDVector pids(1024);
    //вызываем заполнялку первый раз, в качестве функции-заполнителя выступает EnumProcesses
    if(!autoFill<PIDVector>(pids, &EnumProcesses))
    {
        return;
    }

    wcout << pids.size() << L" processes found";


    for(const auto& i:pids)
    {    
        const auto cur=OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,i);

        if(!cur)
        {
            lout.fail();
            continue;
        }


        wstring name;
        //второй раз сложнее - GetProcessImageFileNameW работает по тому же шаблону, что и EnumProcesses, но аргументы принимает иначе
        //справляемся с этим, затолкав ее в адаптер из функтора
        autoFill(name,[cur](wchar_t* str,DWORD size,DWORD* needed)
                         {
                             *needed=GetProcessImageFileNameW(cur,str,size/sizeof(wchar_t))*sizeof(wchar_t);

                             return TRUE;
                         }
                );    
        wcout << name;
    }
    return;
}
```

Магия с шаблоном тут сделана потому, что нужно дважды делать вызов функции с одинаковым паттерном

- вызывать
- проверить, что функции хватило буфера
- если нехватило, повторить

Чтобы не писать два раза идентичный по форме код, я сочинил шаблон.

Comment: а после оператора while что значит optional<bool>  и QString это переменная ?  Но что она означает?( Это вывод названия процесса?)

Comment: Подупростил. Функция выводит процессы на консоль.

Comment: Я немного путаюсь, как приду домой я разобью код на несколько частей и буду спрашивать по мере изучения. Спасибо что откликнулся.

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить список процессов используя wtsapi32. API доступно с Windows XP

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "WtsApi32.h"

WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;
DWORD dwProcCount = 0;
if (WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWPIs, &dwProcCount))
{
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwProcCount; i++) {
        std::wcout << pWPIs[i].pProcessName << std::endl;
    }
}

if (pWPIs)
{
    WTSFreeMemory(pWPIs);
}
```

---

[Оригинальный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477097/get-full-running-process-list-visual-c) [EN SO]

Comment: Это метод вывода информации о процесе?(WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;), а почему присваивается значение NULL?

Comment: @Артем Это метод вывода информации о процесе?(WTS_PROCESS_INFO* pWPIs = NULL;), а почему присваивается значение NULL?  Потом вводиться переменная dwProcCount, и с помощью оператора if  выводятся все процессы . Что значит вот эта строчка 
 WTSEnumerateProcesses(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWPIs, &dwProcCount) пересчитываются все переменные?  А во втором операторе if идёт проверка хватит ли памяти?

Comment: Это определение локальной переменной для списка процессов.

Comment: У этого способа есть небольшой недостаток - он выдает только имена файлов, но не полные пути

Comment: @gbg Согласен, но в структуре [WTS_PROCESS_INFOA](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/ns-wtsapi32-wts_process_infoa) есть `pid`, потому это не исключает дальнейшие манипуляции.

Comment: @gbg Можно [ещё один способ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/toolhelp/process-walking?redirectedfrom=MSDN) описать здесь, кстати. Хотя автору и всеравно на ответы.